# Defining a list of list with a loop in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to define a list of lists with a loop in Python. 
I want to construct the following list:

```
x=[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],...,[9,0]]
```

Here is basically what I do:

```
x=[[0,0]]*10
for i in range(10):
    x[i][0]=i
print x
```

However, I end up with the following list:

```
x=[[9,0],[9,0],[9,0],...,[9,0]]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You are creating repeated references to the same list, not 10 new lists. `[[i, 0] for i in range(10)]` would create new nested lists.

Comment: All the comments and answers were very helpful and instructive. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
>>> [[i, 0] for i in range(10)]
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 0], [6, 0], [7, 0], [8, 0], [9, 0]]
```

What was wrong with that you were doing is that you were creating a list, and then by using the `*` you were not creating more, you were just making more references to it, this means that each time you changed the list, you were changing the *same* list each time.

```
>>> a = [[]]*10
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[0].append('X')
>>> a
[['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X'], ['X']]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
x=[[0,0]]*10
```

you are not creating 10 different elements, but simply copying the reference to the same element 10 times. What you actually need is

```
x=[[i,0] for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
a=[[0,i] for i in range(10)]
print a
```

output is like:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9]]
```