# Navigating nested lists in python

Tags: python, list

This is probably very basic, but I am having trouble navigating nested lists in python 3.

```
list1 = [[0]*3]*3
list1[0][1] = 1
print(list1)
```

Produces the output

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

when I expected the output to be

```
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Dup: [Python List Index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index) and many more...

Comment: For the same reason explained in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19906002/1561176).